# Lowest technology method to prove fundamental theory of galois theory in characteristic zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I wish to learn the proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem. I only care about what happens in characteristic zero. What's the method that gets me to a proof with the lowest level of technology?

I don't mind if the proof is *long*, if it illuminates what is actually going on. I've learnt a proof from Artin of the fundamental theory of galois theory, plus the fact that $S_n$ isn't solvable, but I don't feel I've gained any enlightenment from this.

I'm looking for a computational/mechanical/low level method to *understand* what's going on in the proof of Galois theory.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn from? Regardless, classical Galois theory is a pretty old theory and I don't think its exposition can be improved or streamlined much beyond what's done in standard first courses in Galois theory. I recommend reading Stewart's book.

Comment: You need to know how to construct the splitting field as a tower of simple extensions (factoring the polynomial repeatedly in the extensions) and the Galois group as all the $K$ embeddings $L\to \overline{L}$ and use it to show that $|Gal(L/k)| = [L:K]$. Next, prove that $K$ is the subfield of $L$ fixed by $Gal(L/K)$. The correspondence between the subgroups and their fixed fields is almost immediate from there.

Comment: See [this series of blog posts](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/12/abel-and-the-insolvability-of-the-quintic-part-1.html?m=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leonard Dickson in some of his books (for instance (Modern) Algebraic Theories) does a nice job of presenting the Galois theory from first principles. It's interesting, if you want to see the way it was probably done by Galois itself.